# Google Maps Geolocation API

Tags: google-maps

Im writing an application that gets the geolocation from a given MAC address 
I implemented a client as shown on the tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#auth

all I get back is a result of geocoordinates:
Longitude: -6.3150542
Latitude: 53.3603142
this is independent from the Mac I enter. 
Has anyone successfully implemented a client that works with this API ?

Answer (score 0):

The Geolocation Maps API you are using return JSON which consist of Latitude, Longitude and accuracy. If you are getting this response then your implementation is correct. Make sure to put the MAC address of the access point and not your device in the WifiAccessPoint Object is the body of the POST request.

Later you can parse the JSON for the coordinates to display on the maps or display as toast or textview. The Geolocation API figures out the approximate location your device by location the cell tower or the Wi-Fi access point from where you are getting your internet data/connection.