# HTML Geolocation API vs. php IP with database

Tags: javascript, php

I want to know where my users are from. There are two methods I came across.

PHP:

```
$ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$ip_with_proxy=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

Then compare the IP to a database of longitude/latitude.

OR

HTML Geolocation API (Request from user using JS):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Which one will give me more accurate longitude/latitude? Does the request from user method have the problem of proxy locations?

I was thinking that I could request the users geolocation using JS, and if the user denies the request, use IP to find the general location. But I would only do this if JS request method is more accurate. I understand that the PHP method is dependent on the accuracy of my database, but is the JS method generally more accurate?

I would like a precise location compared to a general location. I would rather have the location on or around the users house compared to just the city or country.

What are the main differences in accuracy? And where does the HTML Geolocation API get its data from?

Comment: your db will be obsolete in a while, it's better to use an online api.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well. Thanks for the comment

Comment: IP-Adresses will never give you an exact location. Just think of mobiles,... So in your case you'd a combination of "asking the user" (and use the users browser api) with a fallback to ip via online api - I guess.

Comment: Does anyone know how long the API request session will last? If the user comes back later.

Comment: A review of these 4000 similar questions might yield an answer: [geolocation questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=geolocation+javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript method only works if the user has gps. Generally smartphones have gps but computers/servers do not. The gps method is fairly accurate. The php method is not accurate at all really. Google uses the php method and it tells me I am in my nearest city because that is where my internet service provider is based.

Comment: The HTML5 Geolocation API doesn't use IP address at all? So how does it get location from computers?

Comment: I just did a test - just because beeing curious: a Destop connected to MobileHotspot without gps locates me only 300meters off on GMaps. So IP on mobile might even be better than IP via real ISP.

Comment: @MaciekSemik I get a result similar to a previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825601/google-maps-geolocation-api when using html5 geolocation on a desktop with no gps. A result which tells me I have it setup correctly.